# Compare two computers

Tags: iphone, performance, comparison, benchmarking

I would like to compare my notebook with my iPhone (about power (speed)). i need something that is really "official" or let's me make a clear statement because I'm using it for a bachelor thesis. is there something like a well known benchmark, or is it possible i write something on my own?

Comment: There are a number of common benchmarks but they all attempt to measure different things. Until you define what aspects of a device's performance you care about I don't know how to suggest one. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing) for a start.

Comment: hi thx for the links, i guess you're right joshua. didn't know this site.

Comment: Don't forget there is also: http://Apple.StackExchange.com/ for more related iPhone/iPod questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Linpack benchmark
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK

Comment: thx for that there is also an app for the iphone already. it is called linpack benchmark.

Comment: oh and if someone is interested my results are: macbook pro 13", 2,4GHz, 4Mb Ram 128 ssd: 798.413 Mflop/s in 0.11s vs. iPhone 3GS: 24.61 Mflop/s and 0.22s. sry again for the double posting. @Matthew: i would like to give you some credit but because of double posting this topic i lost my reputations :(